# How to detect which one object i touched in sceneView at ARKitExample?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

in Apple's `ARKitExample`, if i add multiple virtual objects（two chair） in one scene view. How to detect which one chair i touched in `sceneView` at `ARKitExample`?

the `sceneView.hitTest()` function will return the array of `SCNHitTestResult`, but the `result.node` is kind class of `SCNNode`, i don't know the object i touched is which one chair?

Dose anyone could help this? Thanks a lots

Answer (score 2):

You are respondsible for tracking which nodes belong to which objects.  I usually use a Set since SCNNode is hashable.  You can then easily test if the node belongs to one of the objects you are interested in:

```
guard let result = sceneView.hitTest(location, options: nil).first else {
    return
}
if myObjectNodes.contains(result.node) { //myObjectNodes is declared as  Set<SCNNode>
    //This is a match
}
```

Comment: In `ARKitExample`, the name of virtual object was used to detect which one is touched. So, give "chair1" and "chair2" to 2 chair objects, then i could detect which one i touched with name.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the answer from @JoshHomann, you can do something like this

**Swift 4**

```
 override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch = touches.first as! UITouch
        if(touch.view == self.sceneView){
            print("touch working")
            let viewTouchLocation:CGPoint = touch.location(in: sceneView)
            guard let result = sceneView.hitTest(viewTouchLocation, options: nil).first else {
                return
            }
            if myObjectNodes.contains(result.node) { //myObjectNodes is declared as  Set<SCNNode>
                print("match")
            }

        }
    }
```